# Background bigger than iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am building a joomla site.
I have made a simple custom module showing an image (800x500).
I have another module with an iframe. (It shows video from livestream.com).
Can I use the above image (800x500) as a background for the iframe? 
The iframe is smaller than the image. I would like to put it in the center of the above image. I don't care about transparency.So, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your image as a background (of a div), then put your iframe in the div?

```
<div style='width:180px;height:150px;background:#c33;
 display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center'>
  <div style='width:140px;height:140px;background:#3c3'>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Logo/pen/zxGvxQ)